# Remap "RCtrl + Arrow" to "End" but keep other modifiers

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to replace the <kbd>RControl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>, but I want to keep other modifiers functionality (like combining it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or even <kbd>Control</kbd> for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>).

I tried:

- `*>^Right::End` - doesn't ignore the `RControl`, so I am unable to press `End`, only `Control+End`.
- `*>^Right::Send {End}` - doesn't send my other modifiers, so even if I do `Shift + RControl + Right` it will register only `End`.

As far as I could find information, the second one should work fine because of the `*` on it (it should let other modifiers go through), but it's not working.

Any tips on this? This is really hurting my productivity as my new keyboard have the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on the right side and I always use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+Keys for Home/End and I can't seem to find a good alternative on my current layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Send` with [blind mode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#blind) to allow all modifiers except <kbd>RControl</kbd> to pass through:

```
*>^Right::Send {Blind}{RCtrl Up}{End}
```

This is like what your first try (`*>^Right::End`) does [internally](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#blind-pitfall); it just doesn't send `{RCtrl Up}`.

Comment: I am using `*>^Right::Send {Blind}{RControl Up}{End}{RControl Down}` for now, but as I want to create a "keyboard layer" and replace a whole bunch of functionality, I would like to try easier/cleaner solutions, specially for later maintenance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your question only asks how to use Right Control + Right Arrow for End while preserving other modifiers and as far as I know this is the easiest way to do so in AHK.

Comment: I thought per documentation that `*>^Right::End` would work (and also handle the down/up cases automatically) but that's not working for me. I wanted to also know what the problem is with that syntax or if there is something wrong in the docs/AHK itself.

Comment: [I linked to the part of the docs which addresses this exact problem](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#blind-pitfall). It doesn't work because [remapping actually uses `Send {Blind}`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually), which [doesn't release RCtrl automatically](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#blind). So, the remapping `*>^Right::End` is essentially `*>^Right::Send {Blind}{End}`, which winds up as RCtrl+(any other modifiers pressed)+End because RCtrl is still pressed and `{Blind}` prevents `Send` from automatically releasing it.